# How to use pymouse on linux?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.x, python-2.5

I have installed pymouse and xlib in python2.5. However, when I run `pip list`, only pymouse can be seen, and when I `import pymouse`, it says:

> no module named `pymouse`

How can I fix this?